# Getting username in a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor-server-side

I'm creating a Blazor server side site and have worked my way through some tutorials about setting up authorisation to the point that I have a working login process using a Custom Authentication State Provider.

My intention is to modify this to access a user table and check the login against it to check access etc. What I would really like to do is to get the system username so I can do this check without having to get the user to go through a typed login process.
All the articles I've seen say to use the AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() method to get these details. The problem is, as I'm using a custom one, its overridden the GetAuthenticationStateAsync method. How do I access the original method?

Comment: You can call the overridden method inside the overriding one like this: `await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()`. However, I don't know if this is the best/cleanest way to get what you want.

Comment: I tried the base call, but you get an error message 'cannot call an abstract base member'